# Formatting legend position in Excel?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I have a bar chart with four different data sets in Excel 2010 and made a nice little figure from it. However, I now want to format my chart's legend.

The legend has four entries in list format with each entry preceded by a colored box indicating its correlation to the chart. So it looks like this:

- First
- Second
- Third
- Fourth

However, the 'second' entry is actually a subset of the 'first', and I want it to be indented to demonstrate this. Same goes for the 'fourth' entry being a subset of the 'third.' However, I can't get Excel to allow me to stagger or indent a single entry in the legend, only the entire legend.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use the text box and delete the legend.

[image]

The words Col1, Col1b, Col2 and Col2b and the red/blue boxes are part of a text box which I can control as I like.

To make the square boxes, use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> and then change the font colour.

Of course, you have to manually match the colour and you lose the luxury of what using the legend does, but visually it achieves what you want.

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't expect such a helpful answer. thanks

Comment: Pleasure, glad it works for you. I will point out, to delete the legend, right click and select delete as on my machine, using the delete key on my keyboard killed the entire graph!